# how to find distinct field of a model upon an and condition in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking to find list of the distinct fields of a model which satisfies both the two conditions.

from doc : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct

i found that i can pass an array of conditions as second parameter in `Model.distinct()`. But the array of conditions seems to get linked via an 'or' operation. That is if any one condition satisfies the field is listed.

But i want to get the field only if both conditions are satisfies.

and when i use :

```
Model.distinct(field).and(arrayOfConditions).exec(callback);
```

then i get the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined
    at SchemaBoolean.handleArray (/Users/user1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/boolean.js:56:14)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`distinct` doesn't return a full functioning `Query` object so you would do it like this instead:

```
Model.distinct(field, {$and: arrayOfConditions}).exec(callback);
```

Comment: Model.distinct always returns a Query object. Model.distinct in turn calls Query.distinct which returns a Query object. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct

Comment: however your answer works well.. and also this one : Model.distinct(field, {$and : arrayOfConditions }, callback)