# TypeError: Invalid `field` argument. Must be string or function at CustomQuery.Query.distinct

Tags: javascript, mongoose, conditional-statements, distinct

I am trying to make a query with mongoose's distinct, I read the documentation at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct

the distinct query works fine if I did not use the `conditions` field works fine if I do it like this `await Country.distinct('en.country')`, but

if I do something like `await Country.distinct('en.country', { 'en.country': { $ne: 'some country name' } });` this would give me the error of `TypeError: Invalid field argument. Must be string or function     at CustomQuery.Query.distinct`

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / help.

Comment: `Model.distinct` expects a string according to mongoose not an object

Comment: @KunalMukherjee yes, the first field is a string though, but the second condition field is an Object isn't it? Also in the documentation it shows an object as the second param

Comment: I think it doesn't supports nested fields, like `en.country`, as the documentation shows fields at the root level, you may want to use the aggregation pipeline

Comment: Are you sure your field in first parameter called "en.country"?
Could you share your model? Also i recommend you to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217867/how-to-find-distinct-field-of-a-model-upon-an-and-condition-in-mongoose

Comment: @KunalMukherjee ah ok, if it does not support nested, how can I do it with `aggregation`?

Comment: @ArtemFedotov for sure the param is called `en.country` and I checked the post you sent so I tried something like `await Country.distinct('en.country', { $and : [{ 'en.country': { $ne: 'blah' } }] });` but same error

Comment: @Dora please share with us your Country model?

Comment: The distinct operation with the condition provided in the question looks correct. What is the version of the mongoose library you are using?

Comment: @Vishnu it's actually `sails-mongo@1.2.0` becuase it's `sailsjs` framework and using `getDatastore().manager` so able to use the native mongo query since the normal sailsjs has some restrictions.  But now you mention this, Could it be because, `sails-mongo` actually doesn't provide such field :|

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation pipeline -

1. Start by [`filtering out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match) the country name documents not matching with `some country name`
2. [`Group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) by `en.country` key and count the number of its occurrences.
3. [`Filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match) only those countries that have occurrences as 1.
4. [`Project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) the result back

---

```
await Country.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'en.country': { 
                $ne: 'some country name' 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$en.country',
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            },
            countryName: {
                $first: '$en.country'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: {
                $eq: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            country: '$countryName'
        }
    }
]).exec();
```